# Use selenium to enter date in text field with changing ID

Tags: selenium-ide

I have 2 date input text fields with an ID that keeps changing. Now you see 1c and 1d, but that can also be 4 and 5, or 8 and 9. What value do I need to enter in Selenium to ignore that changing field, but find the 2 boxes?

```
<div class="dateInputField" style="z-index: 980;">
<input id="id1c" type="text" name="dateFrom:date" value="" size="8">
<span class="yui-skin-sam">`

<div class="rowElem required" style="z-index: 990;">
<div class="dateInputField" style="z-index: 1000;">
<input id="id1d" type="text" name="dateTill:date" value="" size="8">
<span class="yui-skin-sam">`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Name (I assume the name doesn't change?) or XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Use NAME as the element identifier like this 
type | name=dateFrom:date | 01/01/2001

Hope that helps.